# PaddingLeft of afterFit does not work during chart.js option

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I want padding at the beginning of the X-axis as shown in the image below.

But padding doesn't work in my code.

What's the matter?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7K8d.png)

My Chart Screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvcjF.png)

Chart.js Version 2.9.4

here is code

html

```
  <div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:40vh; width:80vw">
 </div>
```

javascript

```
$('#myChart').remove();
$('.chart-container').append('<canvas id="myChart" style="height:400vh; width:500vw;"></canvas>');



let options = {
spanGaps: true,
responsive: true,
maintainAspectRatio : false,
scales: {
    xAxes:[{
        afterFit:(axis)=>{
            // console.log(axis)
            axis.paddingLeft = 25;
            axis.paddingRight = 15;
        },
        // padding : 20,
        ticks: {
            fontSize: 15,
            padding :20,
            drawTicks:true,
            offset: true,
            // labelOffset: 70,
            userCallback: function(value, index, values) {...},
        },
        gridLines:{
            display: xLineState,
            lineWidth: xLine,
            // offsetGridLines: true
        },
    }],
    yAxes: [{
        afterFit:(axis)=>{
        },
        padding : 10,
        ticks: {
            // min:10,
            fontSize: 15,
            padding :15,
            beginAtZero: true,
            userCallback: function(value, index, values) {...}
        },
        gridLines:{
            display: yLineState,
            lineWidth: yLine
        }
    }],

},
scaleLabel: {
    display: true,
    labelString: 'Moola',
    fontSize: 20,
},
tooltips: {
    enabled: false,
    mode: 'index',
    position: 'nearest',
    custom: customTooltips,
    callbacks:
        {
            label:function (tooltipItem, data) {...},
            footer:function (tooltipItems, data) {...}
        }
},
legend:{
    labels: {
        fontSize: legendFontSize,
    },
    onClick:function (e,legendItem) {...}
}};



        new Chart(ctx, config);
```

I want padding at the beginning of the X-axis as shown in the image below.

But padding doesn't work in my code.

What's the matter?
paddingLeft is not working..plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong, it seems like it is a bug in chart.js. version 2.4.0 is the latest version I can see it works in.

Working example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        afterFit: (axis) => {
          // console.log(axis)
          axis.paddingLeft = 25;
          axis.paddingRight = 15;
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-K89oirx9CqibxV7RiVHkr4Bu5l9ZCUGt8sKQGMAFWM1gfmjXYNp0/IsL94rzQCjzOUYU8yNN4TiOQ7Vx8J1Iig==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/dxrm918n/2/
Filed an issue for this on there git: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/8344

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I will test with downgrade of chart js version.